# How to deal with NaT/1970 dates so that python-xarray ds.time.dt.season works?

Tags: python-xarray

I have this python-xarray dataset:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (airport: 8, profnum: 9993, level: 3)
Coordinates:
  * airport       (airport) <U9 'Frankfurt' 'Windhoek' ... 'Madras' 'Hyderabad'
  * profnum       (profnum) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 9987 9988 9989 9990 9991 9992
  * level         (level) int64 0 1 2
    time          (airport, profnum, level) datetime64[ns] 2008-01-01T10:27:0...
    yearMonthDay  (airport, profnum, level) object '08-01-01' '08-01-01' ... nan
Data variables:
    iasi          (airport, profnum, level) float64 0.5094 1.345 ... nan nan
    IM            (airport, profnum, level) float64 0.515 1.775 ... nan nan
    IMS           (airport, profnum, level) float64 0.5221 1.514 ... nan nan
    err           (airport, profnum, level) float64 0.04518 0.2714 ... nan nan
    std           (airport, profnum, level) float64 0.0324 0.1542 ... nan nan
    dfs           (airport, profnum, level) float64 1.476 nan nan ... nan nan
```

ds.time shows some 1970-01-01 dates that I manage to change to np.datetime64("NaT") if needed but ds.time.dt.season don't like them. So I do:

```
ds = ds.where( (ds.time.dt.year >= 2008) & (ds.time.dt.year <= currentYear), drop=True)
ds = ds.where( (ds.time.dt.year >= 2008) & (ds.time.dt.year <= currentYear), other=np.nan )
```

I expect that after this I don't see any 1970 date with ds.time, but replacement does not work.

It looks like "other" expect a float because

```
ds.where( (ds.time.dt.year >= 2008) & (ds.time.dt.year <= currentYear), other=np.datetime64("NaT"))
```

outputs

```
TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.
```

Which is strange since df.time is datetime64.

Thank you

Comment: can you be more specific than "stupid" in describing the dates that are causing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```py
ds.where(
    (ds.time.dt.year >= 2008) & (ds.time.dt.year <= currentYear),
    other=np.datetime64("NaT"),
)
```

can be interpreted as

> wherever 2008 ≤ year ≤ currentYear, return ds, otherwise return `NaT`

This causes problems because this operation is carried out for each *variable* in your dataset. Because all of your data_variables are type `float64`, you are recieving this error. To only replace values in time, limit your condition to `ds.time`:

```py
ds.time.where(
    (ds.time.dt.year >= 2008) & (ds.time.dt.year <= currentYear),
    other=np.datetime64("NaT"),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I better understand. Unfortunately ds.time.dt.season still does not like NaT.  "ds.time.dt.season" gives IndexError "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"

Comment: Can you post the code that gives this, including the actual problematic values?

Comment: Thank you Michael. It looks like this season getter was not made to handle NaT. I modified the xarray code and I will push it soon : _season_from_months() in https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/eea76733770be03e78a0834803291659136bca31/xarray/core/accessor_dt.py#L16